# grails 3.3.10 not timing out after setting server.connection-timeout

Tags: grails, tomcat8, grails-3.3

We are trying to diagnose a timeout issue, by trying to set the `server.connection-timeout` in application.yml

To explore solutions, we first try to cause a connection timeout.
The idea is to set the timeout to 10s and cause a timeout in a GSP page.
However, we find that we are unable to cause the server timeout, by modifying the index.gsp and adding a `Thread.sleep(20000)`.

Replication instructions:

- Create a grails appliction from grails forge:

  ```
  curl -O start.grails.org/timeout.zip -d version=3.3.10 -d features=events,geb,hibernate5,json-views
  ```
- Modify application.yml

  ```
  server:
      connection-timeout: 10000
  ```
- Add a sleep loop in index.jsp

  ```
  <%
      Thread.sleep(20000)
  %>
  ```
- load up the default page of the application upon startup

Notes:

- By debugging the Tomcat lifecycle, I can see that the embedded servlet container is assigned the 10000ms configuration during initialization.
- If I change the sleep loop to 65s, I still don't get a timeout. Most of the documentation mentions that the default value is the 60s)